# Make mysql query connect to the selected table in a drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working mysql query that retrieves data from table1.

Now I will add every month a new table (table2, table3..etc).

Goal 1 : I would like to add a drop down menu and populate it with all tables as user options.

Goal 2 : I would like to make the query connect to the table that the user selects from the drop down menu, retrieves data and then refresh the page or just the table's div to display updated data.

my current mysql/php code :

```
$query = "SELECT X, Y, Z FROM **table1**";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

{
echo $row['X'];

echo $row['Y'];

echo $row['Z'];
}
```

Instead of "table1" it should be a variable linked to the drop down menu that the user selects.

I feel it should be simple, but I am bit new to this and could not find a similar case.

Thanks a lot gents.

Comment: If all the tables have the same fields, why use different tables? Just add a 4th column to a SINGLE table so you can which records belong to which "section".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Marc, I have just gone ONE table now, am a bit concerned about performance later on as the table gets bigger but it's a long way to go as only like 100 or 200 new rows would be added every month...so until then lets stay with a single table. Now I will try COLD TOLD's answer to put a user variable inside the php code to query specific data.

Comment: Worry once you reach a few million rows. ~2400/year is basically NOTHING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the comment above but here is an example not sure if that what you are looking for

```
<form action="process.php" method='post'>
        <select name="tables">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

process.php file

```
 $table=$_POST['tables'];
$query = "SELECT X, Y, Z FROM  ".$table;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

{
echo $row['X'];

echo $row['Y'];

echo $row['Z'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try and revert back to you.

Comment: Works thanks a million. Am a bit unsure about what Should I put in front of the form action="", am i supposed to put the url of my processing page? Also when I select an option and hit submit the query is processed on the new page but then the default option is displayed inside the dropdown menu instead of the processed option...

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = 'SHOW TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr];';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Tables_from_db_name'];
}
```